# Jquery on one page update another page?

Tags: php, jquery, append, submit

Is it possible for a JQuery script on one page to update form elements on another page ?

Currently on my main page I have 3 dropdown lists with the ID's A,B and C

Each list looks similar this :

```
<select id='A' name='A' >
<option></option>
<option value='012'>012</option>
<option value='076'>076</option>
<option value='195'>195</option>
</select>
```

There are times I need users to add new values to the lists, so I've written a separate page that can create the new entries.

This new page is called from a hyperlink on the main page. Is there anyway when the new page form is submitted, it can force an update of the submit entries available on the main page ?

Due to the main page layout I don't want to reload the whole page just update the dropdown lists A,B & C.

I've just jquery like this beofre to update a dropdown, but that was on  the same page :

```
    var data = data.split(',');
    var $el = $("#A"); $el.empty();

    $.each(data, function(value,key) {
        var data = key.split('#');
        $el.append($("<option></option>").attr("value", data[1]).text(data[0])).prop("disabled", false); 
    });
```

Any ideas ?
Thanks

****UPDATE****

I've nearly got this working.

I've only do it using an alert.. but it's a start !

```
$("#A").click(function() {
    if (this.value.length ===0) { 
      alert('A clicked'); 
    } 
});
```

I have this part working and I've replaced the alert with a AJAX request which is pulling in the correct values and updating the dropdown lists.

Only issue is using the above example it triggers twice. Once with the initial select, and another if you close the dropdown with the blank entry selected.

I know it's doing it because the `value === 0` but is there any way to stop the closing poll ?

Thanks

Comment: pass your data from mainpage to another page and redefine that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a way to have one page update another. Instead, you should have the first page poll for updates.

You could have the page containing the dropdown repeatedly poll the server for any new options to add to the dropdown, using AJAX. To be a little more efficient, only trigger this polling once a user clicks on the link which allows them to add new options to the dropdown.

Comment: Thanks I can see how this could work.  I'm also wondering if it's possible to Poll once they click into the dropdown list ? But not do it again when they select an item. any ideas ?

Comment: This looks like it could work. I've only do it using an alert.. but it's a start ! `$("#A").click(function() {
 if (this.value.length ===0) {
 alert('A clicked');
}
});`

Comment: I'm going to mark @dal102 post as the answer as it pointed me in the right direction... thx